# DB2 Exclude Nulls or set to arbitrary date

Tags: sql, db2

I am having a very difficult time handling null returns in DB2. I've tried IFNULL AND 
COALESCE functions, but I still end up getting  values in the return.

Here is the relevant segment of the query:

```
COALESCE (
    DATE (
        SUBSTR (DIGITS (PODATE),1,2) || char ('/') ||
        SUBSTR (DIGITS (PODATE),3,2) || char ('/') ||
        SUBSTR (DIGITS (PODATE),5,2)
    ),
    DATE ('12/31/99')
) AS PODATE
```

This returns, but I still get nulls. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the type of the PODATE column ?

Comment: The podate column is a legacy column created numeric field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try with an *ISO-formatted* string as Pax implicitly suggested instead of the locale-dependent one you used. This SQL statement **will always work**, regardless of your locale date format setting.

```
SELECT DATE('2009-04-01')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

On a other side, to breakup a numeric field, using **division** and **modulo** is sometime a nice trick. You might then use numeric comparison on it.

With the sample data Pax provided :

```
SELECT 
    MOD(PODATE / 10000, 100) AS YEAR,
    MOD(PODATE / 100, 100) AS MONTH,
    MOD(PODATE, 100) AS DAY
FROM (VALUES (991231), (090101), (null)) AS A (PODATE)
```

But as Pax said : **Dates should be stored in the database as dates, not strings**.
Same for numerical quantities as numerical types, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would, for a start, not coalesce a per-row function like `date()`. You're better off testing the actual field for NULL as in the following example:

```
create table a (podate varchar(8));                                          
insert into a (podate) values ('20090101');
insert into a (podate) values ('20090102');
insert into a (podate) values ('20090103');
insert into a (podate) values (null);
commit;
select
    case when podate is null
        then date('2000-01-01')
        else date(substr(podate,1,4) || '-' ||
                  substr(podate,5,2) || '-' ||
                  substr(podate,7,2))
    end as mydate
from a;
drop table a;
commit;
```

which outputs:

```
---------
MYDATE
----------
2009-01-01
2009-01-02
2009-01-03
2000-01-01
DSNE610I NUMBER OF ROWS DISPLAYED IS 4
```

In your case, the code would look something like:

```
select case when podate is null
       then date('12/31/99')
       else date (substr (podate,1,2) || char ('/') ||
                  substr (podate,3,2) || char ('/') ||
                  substr (podate,5,2)
       end
```

I haven't tested your specific case since my DB/2 is not set up for US date formats. That's something else to look out for as well. This may not work that well on platforms not using US date formats.

Ideally, dates should be stored in the database as dates, not strings. In other words, the conversion costs should be *once* when the data enters a table, not the *millions of times* you're going to extract it. Then your code becomes a simpler and faster:

```
select case when podate is null
       then date('12/31/99')
       else podate
       end
```

or, better if you're never going to have that sentinel date as a real date, don't store `NULL`s at all. Instead, convert them to `date('12/31/99')` as they go into the tables, and use:

```
select podate
```

It doesn't get much simpler or faster than that (assuming you're comfortable with a non-NULL sentinel).

Comment: +1 for *Dates should be stored in the database as dates, not strings*. Best advice. Ever.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful, but I still have an issue when the fields are not null to start with -- that is they were not validated prior to insertion but are null, but null is returned by the date() function when they are converted.